# Detect mouse hover on page load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I wanted to detect whether the mouse was over an element when the web page was loaded. It appears this is not possible with jQuery - mouseover, hover etc. require a mouse move; as does getting the current mouse position (to compare with element bounds).

I have not seen this specific question asked, but have seen people saying the various bits of this aren't possible...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My solution: add a new CSS value with the hover pseudoselector, then test for that. This seems to only work sometimes, however.

CSS:

```
#el:hover {background-color: transparent; }
```

jQuery:

```
if ($('#el').css('background-color') == 'transparent')
```

Comment: This works in more case than most solutions, which is to say never, so I think this is your best bet. Prank sites certainly used this back in the day to determine which sites you had visited through pseudo-selectors, so it's nice to see a legitimate use.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it:

```
/** detect if the mouse was hovering over and element when the page loaded */
function detectHoverOnLoad(options) {
    var sel = options.selector

    if ($(sel + ':hover').length) {
        console.log('loaded while HOVERING over ' + sel)
    } else {
        console.log('loaded, but NOT hovering over ' + sel)
    }
}
```

then I called it like so:

```
detectHoverOnLoad({selector: '#headerNav'})
```

With more testing, I noticed that at times, if the mouse was moving, it did not always detect the hover, so I added a fallback in the else to detect the mouse moving over the element:

```
function detectHoverOnLoad(options) {
    var sel = options.selector

    if ($(sel + ':hover').length) {
        console.log('loaded while HOVERING over ' + sel)
    } else {
        console.log('NOT hovering')
        $(sel).one('mousemove', function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).parents(sel).length) {
                console.log('MOUSEMOVEed over ' + sel)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried to write a JSFiddle to test that (http://jsfiddle.net/FB8se/4/), but there seems to be a problem with the order of events in JSFiddle - as it loads the elements after it's tried to detect which it's floating over - so moved to JSBin and used live preview, but it doesn't seem to work for me: http://jsbin.com/uGUYeQA/1

Comment: @IanGrainger I can't speak to the inner workings of JSFiddle, but it is working for me in the real world.

Comment: and the jsbin? Does that work? If not, what have I done differently?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: after testing, I have concluded this will not work. Save yourself the time and try something else.

I think you can actually make the element bounding box work.

This is a bit of a hack, but the strategy is to use element.offset() to get the coordinates of the element relative to the document, along with element.width() & element.height() to create a bounding box for the mouse position. You can then check an event's .pageX and .pageY values against this bounding box.

As you correctly said, you need an event to get these coordinates, which doesn't work for you since you want them immediately. Nonetheless, have you considered faking a mouse click event by calling $('#some-element').trigger('click') after document load? You could register a function to check the bounding box via $('#some-element).click() beforehand and see what it does.

Comment: Would $('#some-element').trigger('click') give you the current mouse coords? Or some wrong, faked mouse coords?

Comment: After some testing it seems that in most case my crazy idea does not usually generate coordinates. Events fired due to trigger() do not seem to be populated with the values of pageX and pageY.

Answer (score 0):

Why not! :)

Here is a solution of mine:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/dJgf4/)

Code from the demo:

```
function handler(ev) {
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var elId = target.attr('id');
    if( target.is(".el") ) {
       alert('The mouse was over'+ elId );
    }
}
$(".el").mouseleave(handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way that is possible in the world!
forget about JQ hover use its .mouseover and .mouseleave and define functions for both of them, it does not make any problem on load and after load!

```
   $('li').mouseover(function () {
       codes
   } 


   $('li').mouseleave(function () {
       codes
   }
```

Comment: But as I said in my post, I'm running a function already, i want to know what the mouse is over. Not wait until the mouse GOES over something, that's easy!