# jQuery: How to check if the mouse is over an element

Tags: jquery

I have a deferred function that binds a mouseenter event:

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
  var $container = $('.container');
  $container.mouseenter(function(e) {
    //do something
  });
  ...
});
```

The problem is the mouse might already be over the element when the load event fires, hence before the mouseenter event was bound.
I can get around this by putting some code at the end of the page load handler to do a one-time check if the mouse is inside the element and trigger the mouseenter event manually:

```
// check if the mouse is inside $container
if(mouse is inside $container)
  $container.mouseenter();
```

How can I check if the mouse is over the element in the load event?

I tried `$container.is(':hover')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried mouseenter and mouseleave events?

Comment: `$container.is(':hover')` – in what way doesn't that work? My concern would be that it isn't particularly cross-compatible (it won't work in IE7, for instance, because it relies upon qSA behaviour), but it seems to do what you're looking for to me...

Comment: @lonesomeday: see http://jsfiddle.net/UVJgF/1/ and put your mouse over the black box and hit ctr+enter.  it doesn't fire on FF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the css hover solution in [Detect mouse hover on page load with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586166/detect-mouse-hover-on-page-load-with-jquery#answer-6593995) because it doesn't require the mousemove event.

Answer (score 2):

i dont test it yet but  think you want like this...

```
function checkMouseCollision(obj) {
    var offset = obj.offset();
    objX= offset.left;
    objY=offset.top;
    objW=obj.width();
    objH=obj.height();

    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    $().mousemove( function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    });

    if((mouseX>objX&&mouseX<objX+objW)&&(mouseY>objY&&mouseY<objY+objH)){
        alert("hovered")     
    };
};
checkCollision($(".box"))
```

Comment: This could work but the mousemove is going to get called a lot. I would love a way to do a one-time check if possible :)

Comment: @spb have you looked into using .one() instead of .on() for your events?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to get the left, right, top, and bottom offset of the element and see if the mouse position lies anywhere between those values.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/tEgCv/show/).

Put your mouse over the div the first time it loads. Then refresh the page (click F5 so you don't have to move the mouse). When the page loads fully next time, it should alert with "Hover!" even if you haven't moved your mouse.

Or an even easier way. Just check the `e.target.id` of the mousemove event (which apparently fires once the page loads, even without moving the mouse) against the `id` of the element, like so:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if( e.target.id === 'hoverTest'){
        alert("Hovered!");
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/Kh3bp/show/) (do the same steps as above).

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix it on FF8.  To be clear - if I put the mouse over the block and get the first hover popup and press enter, then F5 (or Ctrl-F5) to refresh, I don't get another popup even though the mouse is over the box until I move the mouse a little bit.

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome--looks like another cross-browser mess. Which one is producing that error for you?

Comment: FireFox 8.0  On Chrome 16.0.912.59 on the Cr-48 laptop it keeps popping up the alert even when the mouse isn't moving, so it's difficult to test, but I clicked don't popup again and moved over the box and then hit F5 and it didn't popup until I started moving the mouse, and then it kept popping up.

Comment: @Purmou: A variant of this could work: in the mousemove I could check whether the mouse is over the element and set a flag true or false.  Then I can check that flag in the window.load event handler.  If there isn't a simpler way I will do this.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery 1.7+ you're going to want to use `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("mouseover", "your_element_selector_here", function() {
        // do stuff here
    });
});
```

.live is deprecated. You could also put any other events in .on as well, depending on what you need. :hover doesn't work because it only works with specific elements and it's css based.

Using this in conjunction with an offset detection approach for before the page finishes loading will get you where you want to be.

Comment: interesting.  is .mouseenter or .mouseover deprecated too?  those seem less verbose than .on

Comment: No, but you should use .on(). Like the older deprecated .live, the binding will exist even if the bound element (your_element_here) is redrawn via an ajax redraw. here's the catch though, it's parent element (the one you call 'on' on) must not be redrawn through the course of the page's life. As it is what .on() is assigned to it must always exist.

Answer (score -1):

[Mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event does exactly what you want.

If the `.conteiner` does not exist in time you attach the mouseover event (is added dynamically in the future) you have to use [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to attach the event.

```
$(".conteiner").live("mouseover", function() {
   alert("hovered!");
})
```

**It will work also when the mouse is already on the position, where the new element appears.** [Example here!](http://jsfiddle.net/QtBxH/)

For jQuery 1.7+ you should use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead as the .live method is deprecated. [Example here!](http://jsfiddle.net/HJZ9P/)

Comment: I'm hoping there is a way to check without using events.

Comment: If the mouse is already over an element when the page loads, the `mouseover` event won't fire. That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: Are you sure the `mouseover` event won't fire?

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.container').mouseover(function(e) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: I need to wait for the page to load first though, and by that time the mouse could already be over the element.