# Checking to see when your mouse is contained in the bounds of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ii am trying to check if my mouse is in the form element using jquery. I am using offset, width, and height functions to calculate the bounds of the form. Then I use a conditional to determine if the current mouse position is in those bonds. Currently my conditional always evaluates to true wen it should not.

```js
$('body').mousemove(function(event){
  var form = $('#get-started-form');

  if(form.parent().css('display') == 'block'){
   var height = form.height();
   var width = form.width();
   var offset = form.offset();
   var left = offset.left;
   var top = offset.top;
   var bottom = top + height;
   var right = left + width;

   console.log('.........................................');
   console.log('left: ' + left);
   console.log('right: ' + right);
   console.log('top: ' + top);
   console.log('bottom: ' + bottom);
   console.log('x: ' + event.pageX);
   console.log('y: ' + event.pageY);

   if((left < event.pageX < right) && (top < event.pageY < bottom)){
    console.log('in form')
    console.log((left + '<' + event.pageX + '<' + right))
    console.log((left < event.pageX < right))
   }else{
    console.log('outside');
   }
  }

 });
```

```html
<form id="get-started-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
       <div class="input-group zipcode-row">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" maxlength="5" placeholder="ZIP Code" value="" aria-required="true" class="form-control" aria-invalid="false">
        <span class="fa fa-check-circle valid_check" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-times-circle invalid_x" style="display: none;"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group gender-row">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="M" aria-required="true" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <label for="male" class="gender-choice choice-male float-left">
         <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-mars fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
         Male
        </label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="F" class="form-control">
        <label for="female" class="gender-choice choice-female float-right">
         <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-venus  fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
         Female
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group dob-row">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
        </span>
        <input type="tel" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" aria-required="true" class="form-control" aria-invalid="true">
        <span class="fa fa-check-circle valid_check" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-times-circle invalid_x" style="display: none;"></span>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="CONTINUE">
       <input type="hidden" name="city" id="city">
       <input type="hidden" name="state" id="state">
       <input type="hidden" id="leadid_token" name="lead_id" value="">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="get_started_form_submit">

      </form>
```

Here is a case that the mouse is not in the form but it still shows true.

```
left: 745
right: 1057
top: 286
bottom: 557.313
x: 1633
y: 0
in form
745<1633<1057
true
```

Comment: I think you may be doing this in a more complex way than you need to. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597663/jquery-how-to-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element. There are a few tricks, but searching SO for 'check if pointer is inside an element' should net you some promising results.

Comment: Your code is massively more complex than it needs to be. Attach a `mousemove` event to the `form` element, then use the properties of the event given to the event handler to find the mouse position, eg. `offsetX` and `offsetY`

Comment: Just change the if : if((left < event.pageX && event.pageX < right) && (top < event.pageY && event.pageY < bottom))