# Hover on load doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, hover

Demo: http://jsbin.com/afixay/3/edit

1) place cursor over red box

2) don't move cursor, just hit ctrl+r (page should be reloaded)

3) you'll get no alert.

Well, you will get an alert once you unhover/hover it back. The problem is, when cursor is placed over red box on a page load, `hover` event is not fired (also no `mouseenter`).

How do I fix this?

I know, browser's work seems to be true, but I really need to know if an element is hovered, even on page load.

```
$(function() {
  function hovered(e){
      e.type == 'mouseenter' ? alert('on') : alert('off'); 
  }

  $('.box').hover(hovered);
});
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping all the JS code there in `$(function() { //your code });`? This will have it run on document.(ready)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586166/detect-mouse-hover-on-page-load-with-jquery

Comment: @John it doesn't help

Comment: @flemingslone not a right solution, because this is needed for plugin, user can remove css line and bug will appear again

Comment: I seem to be getting an alert using Chrome ?

Comment: @adeneo You get an alert when reloading the page with the cursor over the area? I am using Chrome 25.0.1364.172 and not getting it as desired.

Comment: I am definitely getting an alert('on') after step 2. Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172 m

Comment: I'm not getting the alert (Chrome 26 on Mac). See answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to do this, not with pure JS anyway.

1. You cannot get the mouse position manually on initial page load until there is an event fired. X and Y positions are 0. So there's no way to tell if the mouse is already over your element.
2. No mouse events are fired until it moves. You could listen for mousemove to immediately respond, but that still doesn't give you what you want.

The [CSS trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586166/detect-mouse-hover-on-page-load-with-jquery) that was pointed out in the comments is the closest you'll get, but it's hardly a solid solution.